# Can’t set color of vim

Tags: bash, vim, centos

I’ve tried to set color of vim for editing C program text file.

My .vimrc is below.

[.vimrc]

```
set nu
colorscheme delek
syntax on
```

And `delek.vim` file is as follwing list.

```
ls -la /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors
total 80
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Jun 14  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root root 4096 Jun 14  2013 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2476 Apr  5  2012 blue.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2990 Apr  5  2012 darkblue.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  548 Apr  5  2012 default.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2399 Apr  5  2012 delek.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2812 Apr  5  2012 desert.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1666 Apr  5  2012 elflord.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2476 Apr  5  2012 evening.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 3306 Apr  5  2012 koehler.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2460 Apr  5  2012 morning.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2006 Apr  5  2012 murphy.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1037 Apr  5  2012 pablo.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2673 Apr  5  2012 peachpuff.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2311 Apr  5  2012 README.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1239 Apr  5  2012 ron.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2720 Apr  5  2012 shine.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2445 Apr  5  2012 slate.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1629 Apr  5  2012 torte.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1840 Apr  5  2012 zellner.vim
$
```

After setting, I re-login and edit C source.

But no words are colored while there is a line under words.

How can I set it?

Comment: Can `:sy` list any syntax items in your case?

Comment: Yes I can.There are some syntax items.

Comment: What is the output of `:set ft?`? Is it `filetype=c`?

Comment: It shows `filetype=c`

Comment: Exactly `filetype=c` <- this is pasted text

Comment: What terminal are you running vim in? What does `:echo &t_Co` in vim say?

Comment: I use `poderosa Version : 4.1.0`. And `:echo &t_Co` doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of

```
:set t_Co?
```

It should print `16` or `256`. If not, your terminal isn't properly detected, and you should check your `$TERM` value. The `:highlight` command will quickly show you what colors and attributes are available. Also check whether other applications (e.g. `mc` or `htop`) can display colors.

Comment: I got it.$TERM must be xterm but it was kterm.Now I can see `#include` colored.